# Nuxt is returning html instead of JSON that I got from the api

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a simple api returning a json object that I want to display unto the screen.
However when I display the $data property I'm getting html and not the json from the api.
However whenever I refresh the page with f5 or manually the data then shows up on the screen and not the html.

{
"data": {
"positions": 2,
"departments": 2,
"paygrades": 8
}
}

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row> {{ $data.dbData }}</v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
      const dbData = await $axios.$get('/dashboard')
      return  dbData 
  },
  data() {
    return {    
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Edited code

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row> {{ dbData }}</v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default { 
  data() {
    return { 
    dbData: null,
    }
  },
async fetch() {   
      this.dbData = await this.$axios.$get('/dashboard')    
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in your network tab?

Comment: What is the `$data` property btw? Why do you even access this one?

Comment: There are 20 requests in network. However i went through all and none of them is making request to port 8000 where my api server is running but im getting the information. (0.0)

Comment: $data just displays what ever you return in the data() of the script tag.

Comment: Filter the requests by XHR and clean the useless ones. You can also always use the  `fetch()` **hook** if you want to be sure. Also, here you do have `dbData` so use `{{ dbData }}` in your template, no need to reach for `$data`.

Comment: okay so i used the fetch hook. when I use the navigation menu to go to the page one network transaction shows up named: dashboard which is the name of my page. further more the json information is under the preview tab so it seems to be working but the html for the page is displayed in the browser

Comment: So, does it work with your edited code?

Comment: no same issue. But i did figure out that its the page code that is being rendered (All the html).

Comment: If you only get JSON, not sure where some HTML may come from. Did you checked the result with Postman to be sure that what you're receiving is correct? Also, can you please make us a [repro] somehow?

Comment: I tested my api with postman and it seemed to be working fine. However I tried an api "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1 " and nuxt is working as it should. updating the data and display the data and not the html. I will have to take a look at my api and i'll let you know.

Comment: So i figured it out. In my nuxt.config i had the baseUrl on the axios object ` 'http://localhost:8000/api`. I removed it from there and used the entire  `  'http://localhost:8000/api/dashboard'` url in the axios.get() method and it is working as it should. Thanks again for all your help!!!